# Change a column in PowerQuery based on another column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I try to make in Excel PowerQuery the equal Operation to SQL Operation:

```
SET ColumnA = "Max" WHERE ColumnC = "George"
```

I know that I can `CREATE` a new `Colum`n with an the `M` expression

```
if ColumnA = "Max" then "George" Else "something"
```

but I don't like to create a third column as I do it again and again.

Any ideas how I could do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain if statements together, like so

`if [ColumnA] = "Max" then "George" else if [ColumnA] = "Jane" then "Janet" else "something"`

You can also create a record that looks up names and then uses the alternate name if it exists. This can be done by creating a record like this in one query:

```
let
    Source = [Max = "George", Jane = "Janet"]
in
    Source
```

Let that query be called Names. Then, when you add a custom column, you can use this expression:

`if Record.HasFields(Names, [ColumnA]) then Record.Field(Names, [ColumnA]) else "something"`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, both are good ideas and will help me in other situations. In the moment, I must cange ColumA again and again, but not in one step.

Comment: I set an initial value and after some steps I must Update ColumnA, then some steps later, I must update it again. This column is for me a status field, I must update the status of some rows if my transformations did result in some special cases.

Comment: If you have to do this for multiple steps, you can use `Table.TransformColumns` for each step to only modify ColumnA. For example, the second suggestion could be turned into:
`Table.TransformColumns(stepName, {"ColumnA",each if Record.HasFields(Names, _) then RecordField.(Names, _) else "something"})`. This will change the cells in ColumnA to use the alternate name, and no new columns will be created. You can make this a function in a separate query and then invoke it multiple times to simplify your code.